# Is it possible to fill the empty cells without using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a sample a of dataframe with banking data. I would like to know if it is possible to fill the empty cells without using a for loop.

In this example, let's say that at the row number 2 (pythonic way), it should take the value of the balance at the previous row `52867,36` and add the amount of the row number 2 : `847.00`.

This happens when there are several transactions on the same date.

It is easy with a for loop but I would like to know if there is a way to do it by a vectorisation.

###### The dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = ['26.10.2022', '27.10.2022', '28.10.2022', '28.10.2022', '28.10.2022','28.10.2022', '31.10.2022', '31.10.2022', '01.11.2022', '01.11.2022', '03.11.2022',  '04.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '08.11.2022', '09.11.2022', '09.11.2022']
l2 = [54267.36,52867.36, '','' , '',52744.21,'' ,52646.91,'',34898.36,34871.46,51026.46,'','',50612.36,61468.52,'',69563.27]
l3 = [-390,-1400,847,-900.15,-45,-25,-57.3,-40,-12528.55,-5220,-26.9,16155,-275,-105,-34.1,10856.16,7663.95,430.8]


df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2,l3)), columns = ['Date','Balance','Amount'])
print(df)


          Date   Balance    Amount
0   26.10.2022  54267.36   -390.00
1   27.10.2022  52867.36  -1400.00
2   28.10.2022              847.00
3   28.10.2022             -900.15
4   28.10.2022              -45.00
5   28.10.2022  52744.21    -25.00
6   31.10.2022              -57.30
7   31.10.2022  52646.91    -40.00
8   01.11.2022           -12528.55
9   01.11.2022  34898.36  -5220.00
10  03.11.2022  34871.46    -26.90
11  04.11.2022  51026.46  16155.00
12  07.11.2022             -275.00
13  07.11.2022             -105.00
14  07.11.2022  50612.36    -34.10
15  08.11.2022  61468.52  10856.16
16  09.11.2022             7663.95
17  09.11.2022  69563.27    430.80
```

Comment: Note that these values are not really empty: they are 0-length strings. As a result, the type of the Balance column is an object; not a float.

Comment: (You might also prefer a specific date format the for the Date column. This is also of object, or string, type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cumsum` on `Amount` column to get difference to the first value of `Balance` then `fillna` value in `Balance` column

```py
df['Balance'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['Balance'])
                 .fillna(df['Amount'].shift(-1).cumsum().add(df.iloc[0]['Balance']).shift(1)))
```

```
print(df)

          Date   Balance    Amount
0   26.10.2022  54267.36   -390.00
1   27.10.2022  52867.36  -1400.00
2   28.10.2022  53714.36    847.00
3   28.10.2022  52814.21   -900.15
4   28.10.2022  52769.21    -45.00
5   28.10.2022  52744.21    -25.00
6   31.10.2022  52686.91    -57.30
7   31.10.2022  52646.91    -40.00
8   01.11.2022  40118.36 -12528.55
9   01.11.2022  34898.36  -5220.00
10  03.11.2022  34871.46    -26.90
11  04.11.2022  51026.46  16155.00
12  07.11.2022  50751.46   -275.00
13  07.11.2022  50646.46   -105.00
14  07.11.2022  50612.36    -34.10
15  08.11.2022  61468.52  10856.16
16  09.11.2022  69132.47   7663.95
17  09.11.2022  69563.27    430.80
```

Comment: to_numeric, fillna, shift, cumsum, add, shift: Ah, just a normal day in Pandas-country.

Comment: why hardcoding `.add(54267.36)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with the pandas solution @Ynjxsjmh posted above, but I went for the stdlib's itertools.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import accumulate

l1 = ['26.10.2022', '27.10.2022', '28.10.2022', '28.10.2022', '28.10.2022','28.10.2022', '31.10.2022', '31.10.2022', '01.11.2022', '01.11.2022', '03.11.2022',  '04.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '07.11.2022', '08.11.2022', '09.11.2022', '09.11.2022']
l2 = [54267.36,52867.36, '','' , '',52744.21,'' ,52646.91,'',34898.36,34871.46,51026.46,'','',50612.36,61468.52,'',69563.27]
l3 = [-390,-1400,847,-900.15,-45,-25,-57.3,-40,-12528.55,-5220,-26.9,16155,-275,-105,-34.1,10856.16,7663.95,430.8]


df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2,l3)), columns = ['Date','Balance','Amount'])
df["Balance"] = df["Balance"].apply(lambda x: None if x == '' else x).astype(float)
df["Balance"] = [df.loc[0, "Balance"]] + list(accumulate(df.loc[2:, "Amount"], initial=df.loc[1, 'Balance']))

print(df)
```

This gives:

```
          Date   Balance    Amount
0   26.10.2022  54267.36   -390.00
1   27.10.2022  52867.36  -1400.00
2   28.10.2022  53714.36    847.00
3   28.10.2022  52814.21   -900.15
4   28.10.2022  52769.21    -45.00
5   28.10.2022  52744.21    -25.00
6   31.10.2022  52686.91    -57.30
7   31.10.2022  52646.91    -40.00
8   01.11.2022  40118.36 -12528.55
9   01.11.2022  34898.36  -5220.00
10  03.11.2022  34871.46    -26.90
11  04.11.2022  51026.46  16155.00
12  07.11.2022  50751.46   -275.00
13  07.11.2022  50646.46   -105.00
14  07.11.2022  50612.36    -34.10
15  08.11.2022  61468.52  10856.16
16  09.11.2022  69132.47   7663.95
17  09.11.2022  69563.27    430.80
```